# Why does socket() return an integer?

Tags: c, sockets

I know that `socket()` returns a handle (an integer one) for the communication instance, like a file descriptor.

I think that (to me at least) it would have made more sense if it returned an opaque pointer (like `FILE*` from `fopen()`), But an integer? How the implementation manages to work using this integer value to differentiate between a communication instance and the other?

(Same thing applies to `open()` I think?)

Comment: Opaque datatypes are evil. Why do you want even more created?

Comment: Well, a POSIX file descriptor is literally just an index; the "state" is maintained in kernel-space (IIRC), so a pointer wouldn't help.  The state underlying a `FILE *` is maintained in user-space.

Comment: Opinion based question.

Comment: For all practical purposes a file descriptor (what `socket` returns) **is opaque**. Internally the OS keeps a table for the process, mapping from that small integer to other information such as a protocol control block et al.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is rhetorical.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth & cnicutar : That's helpful.

Comment: That's a question to be asked to Kernel developers.

Comment: @H2CO3 A rhetorical question is a question that you ask in order to make a point, and to which you don't expect an answer. *How the implementation manages to work using this integer value to differentiate between a communication instance and the other?* is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Caleb Then the title is misleading at best, and the question is too broad. OP is asking "why function X is designed in such and such a way". The answer is "Because the specification says so".

Comment: @H2CO3 "Because the specification says so" is not a useful answer -- it just begs the question of *why* the spec says that. One could reasonably be expected to interpret the title question as "Why was `int` chosen as the return type for `socket()`?" It's hard to see how that's too broad -- a reasonable answer won't require more than a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How the implementation manages to work using this integer value to differentiate between a communication instance and the other?

The details depend on the implementation, but it's safe to assume that the operating system maps the file handle to the appropriate chunk of data. Exactly what the integer *means* doesn't matter -- it could be an index into an array, a number chosen at random and used as an identifier, or something else. All that matters in your code is that the number represents a specific file or socket.

The integer that's returned by `socket()` is a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), i.e. a value that refers to a specific `FILE` data structure. It's often said of Unix that ["everything is a file"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) because the file system is used as an interface to many resources including disk-based files, pipes, devices like printers and terminals, and network connections. Functions that create new file handles, such as `open()`, `accept()`, `pipe()`, and `socket()`, are expected to return the associated file descriptor.